# How to override logging library functions to require mandatory parameters?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

How can I override the functions `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()` `critical()` from the logging library so that whenever I call them I must do so like this: `logger.<level>(msg=<str>, extra={"client": <str>, "status": <str>})`

That is, making it mandatory that I use the builtin `extra` parameter and pass a dict with that structure, so those key-values can be used in the log creation. I do not want to change anything in the root logger, because it's used by other stuff outside my scope, all changes must be at `Logger(__name__)` scope.

Additionally, the log format for my `CustomLogger` should be different from root logger. The root format is `'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'`. Mine should be `'%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | (client)s | (status)s | %(message)s'`

The usability should be something like this:

```
logger = CustomLogger(__name__)

logger.info(msg="Hello world")  # Exception, because no `extra`
logger.info(msg="Hello world", extra={"client": "XYZ123"})  # Exception, because `extra` is missing one key
logger.info(msg="Hello world", extra={"client": "XYZ123", "status": "green"}). # this should work

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.info(msg="Hello world")  # this should work as my changes do not apply to root logger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best approach that is very clean and Pythonic, just use `stacklevel=2` so `logger.py` is abstracted when it is called:

```
import logging

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):  # This function overrides logging.info()
        if "extra" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("Dict 'extra' is required.")

        if "client" not in kwargs["extra"]:
            raise ValueError("Key 'client' in dict 'extra' is required.")
        if "status" not in kwargs["extra"]:
            raise ValueError("Key 'status' in dict 'extra' is required.")

        super().info(msg, stacklevel=2, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your error handling to those methods, then delegate the rest of the work up to the base class using `*args` and `**kwargs` something like

```
import logging

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def info(self, extra, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'client' not in extra:
            raise KeyError('Missing "client" key in extra arg.')
        if 'status' not in extra:
            raise KeyError('Missing "status" key in extra arg.')
        super().info(args, kwargs)
```

and similar for debug(), info(), warning(), error(), and critical(). For example

```
>>> logger = CustomLogger(__name__)
>>> logger.info(msg="Hello world")  # should fail from missing `extra` arg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    logger.info(msg="Hello world")
TypeError: info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'extra'
>>> logger.info(msg="Hello world", extra={"client": "XYZ123"})    # should fail from missing `"status"` key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    logger.info(msg="Hello world", extra={"client": "XYZ123"})
  File "temp.py", line 11, in info
    raise KeyError('Missing "status" key in extra arg.')
KeyError: 'Missing "status" key in extra arg.'
>>> logger.info(msg="Hello world", extra={"client": "XYZ123", "status": "green"})  # should succeed
>>>
```

To remove some code duplication, you could also consider creating a decorator that will add that `extra` argument validation then pass through to those base class methods without the duplicate boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`LoggerAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects) rather than a `Logger` to ensure that the extra parameters are always added. You initialize it like this:

```
logger = LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), extra)
```

and then you can just use `logger` like a `Logger` instance. The `extra` you pass in can be any object that behaves like a dictionary and returns items with `client` and `status` (and any other) keys.

Also, your statement

> Additionally, the log format for my CustomLogger should be different from root logger.

doesn't really make sense with how `logging` works - formatting goes with a `Handler` instance via a `Formatter` instance, and not with a `Logger` instance. See this section in the [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial).